# Calculating the value of a triple integral with a function and its inverse

Tags: calculus

Let $a,b>0$ and $f:[0,a]\to\mathbb{R}$ continuous function, strictly increasing
with $f(0)=0$ and $f(a)=b$. I would like to calculate
$$\int_{0}^{b}\left(\int_{g(y)}^{a}\left(\int_{0}^{x}f(s)\,ds\right)\,dx\right)\,dy$$
where $g=f^{-1}$ (inverse function of $f$)  and $\int_{0}^{a}f(s)\,ds=\sqrt{2}$.

I would like a hint to start only, not the solution.
I think a proper change of variable might help but I don't know.

Comment: Try interchanging the order of integration to be $dsdydx$, then use integration by parts. I'm getting a final answer of $\frac{1}{2}\left(\int_0^af(x)dx\right)^2$

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Matthew: \begin{align}\int_{0}^{b}\left(\int_{g(y)}^{a}\left(\int_{0}^{x}f(s)\,ds\right)\,dx\right)\,dy
&=\int_{0}^{a} \int_{0}^{f(x)}\left(\int_{0}^{x}f(s)\,ds\right)\,dy\,dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{a}\left(\int_{0}^{x}f(s)\,ds\right)f(x)\,dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{a}\left(\int_{0}^{x}f(s)\,ds\right)\frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{x}f(s)\,ds\,dx=:I\\
&=\left.\left(\int_{0}^{x}f(s)\,ds\right)^2\right|_{0}^{a}-I\\
\end{align}
Therefore $I=\frac{1}{2} \left(\int_{0}^{a}f(s)\,ds\right)^2=1$